# Nested forms / controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've picked through many similar question/answers but I'm just not getting what I'm doing wrong -- any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to make a nested form such that when I add a new member, I can select from my available institutions for them to become members of.

I have these 2 models (I know they lack validation)

```
class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members
end
```

and

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :institution
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :institution
end
```

Here's the controller:

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_member, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @members = current_user.members
  end

  def show
    @member = current_user.members.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @members = current_user.members
    @institutions = @members.institution
    @member = Member.new
  end
```

In the `new` def, I used `@members = current_user.members` as it seemed to work correctly in the `index` def.  But the assignment `@institutions = @members.institution` doesn't work -- I get this error:

```
undefined method `institution' for # Member::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x000000028ce4f0>
```

If I look in the db, I see that the members do have valid institution_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Collection**

The error you have is caused by your call to `@members.institution` -- you can't call `institution` on a *collection* -- it's only available on individual objects (IE if you call `@member.institution`)

What you'll want to do is probably use [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) to allow your `member` to join a series of different `institutions`:

```
#app/controllers/members_controller.rb
Class MembersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @members = current_user.members
      @member = Member.new
   end

   def create
      @member = Member.new(member_params)
      @member.save
   end

   private

   def member_params
      params.require(:member).permit(:institution_ids, :other, :member, :attributes)
   end
end

#app/views/members/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @member do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :institution_ids, Institution.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  Apologies for not replying earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to call the institution method for a *collection of records*, I'm not sure if what I'm proposing as a solution is what you are trying to do, but you can only call the institutions method on a single member record...

```
@institutions = []  #initializing array
@members.each do |member|
   @institutions << member.institution
end
```

Now `@institutions` is populated with an array of institution records from members

Comment: It all seems obvious in hindsight -- I guess I need more hindsight!  Worked perfectly!  Thank you.